# How to change a dynamic button text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Created 3 dynamic divs(**sea_p,sea_p_div,div_btns**), inside the third(**div_btns**) created 2 buttons
how can i change the text inside these dynamic buttons **before adding** to body?

```
let div = $(`<div class="Search_div"></div>`)
let p = $(`
          <div class="sea_p">
             <div class="sea_p_div">
                <div class="p_img">
                    <img src="" alt="" width="80" />
                    <div class="div_span">
                        <span class="p_name"></span>
                        <span class="p_surname"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="div_btns">
                    <button class="req_btn req_check1" data-id="">Text1</button>
                    <button class="req_btn req_check2" data-id="">Text2</button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>`)
div.append(p)
//change text here
$('body').append(div)
```

Comment: What is your expected out ?

Comment: how can i change the text inside these dynamic buttons before adding to body?

Comment: You can not change it manually. Its a very odd requirement. You do no have access to those button ? that why you want to chnage them before append ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    let div = $(`<div class="Search_div"></div>`)
    let p = $(`
          <div class="sea_p">
             <div class="sea_p_div">
                <div class="p_img">
                    <img src="" alt="" width="80" />
                    <div class="div_span">
                        <span class="p_name"></span>
                        <span class="p_surname"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="div_btns">
                    <button class="req_btn req_check1" data-id="">Text1</button>
                    <button class="req_btn req_check2" data-id="">Text2</button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>`)

    div.append(p)
    //change text here
    p.find(".req_check1").html('New Text');
    p.find(".req_check2").html('New Text 2');

    $('body').append(div)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can't change a text before adding to body in this manner

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 window.onload = function() {
   $(".req_check1").html('New Text');
   $(".req_check2").html('New Text 2');
 }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text() method of jQuery, on the jQuery object of button whose text you want to change.

**NOTE :** Use it just after appending the p tag to the body.

```js
var buttonWrap = $('.sea_p .div_btns button');
buttonWrap.eq(0).text("Text for button 1");
buttonWrap.eq(1).text("Text for button 2");
```